# How to sort scala list dynamically on multiple fields

Tags: scala, sorting, dynamic, collections

I have a case class

```
case class Employee(name: String, age: Int, joinedDate: Instant)
```

and I have a list of Employees

```
val employees: List[Employee]
```

that holds multiple employees.

I want to sort the list based on multiple fields for example when more than employees have same name, sorting should be on age, similarly when they have same age sorting should be on joinedDate which means I need multiple level of sorting. The sort parameters can be in any order.

There is a `sortBy` method in scala which does sorting on multiple columns i.e. 
     `employees.sortBy(e => (e.name, e.age))`.  But this is static and I need dynamic. Note that sort fields have different data type like Instant, Int and String.

Can this be achieved ??

Comment: Maybe just do multiple `sortBy` one after another ?

Comment: @amer The second sortBy will break the order created by the first one, of course.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov No, it won't, because `sortBy` is stable. You just need to sort by the least significant field first. In this example the order would be `joinedDate` then `age` then `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can build up an `Ordering[Employee]` dynamically. E.g. :

```
val orderings = Map(
  "name" -> Ordering.by[Employee](_.name),
  "age" -> Ordering.by[Employee](_.age),
  "joinedDate" -> Ordering.by[Employee](_.joinedDate)
)

def orderingByColumns(columns: Seq[String]) = columns.map(orderings).reduce(_.orElse(_))
```

You can use it by calling [`sorted`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#sorted[B%3E:A](implicitord:Ordering[B]):C) and passing the ordering explicitly:

```
employees.sorted(orderingByColumns(List("name", "age"))
```

Extending it to handle descending columns is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You could define ordering for `Employee` using [`Ordering.by`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/math/Ordering$.html#by[T,S](f:T=%3ES)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering[S]):scala.math.Ordering[T]) to treat it as a `Tuple`:

```
import java.time.Instant
case class Employee(name: String, age: Int, joinedDate: Instant)

implicit val employeeOrdering: Ordering[Employee] = Ordering.by(Employee.unapply)
```

Testing the ordering:

```
def toInstant(s: String): Instant = {
  import java.time.{LocalDateTime, ZoneId}
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")      
  LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).toInstant
}

val employees = List(
  Employee("John", 30, toInstant("2019-01-02 00:00:00")),
  Employee("Sue",  20, toInstant("2019-01-02 00:00:00")),
  Employee("Dave", 45, toInstant("2019-01-01 00:00:00")),
  Employee("Amy",  25, toInstant("2019-01-01 00:00:00")),
  Employee("John", 20, toInstant("2019-01-03 00:00:00"))
)

employees.sorted
// res1: List[Employee] = List(
//   Employee("Amy",  25, 2019-01-01T08:00:00Z),
//   Employee("Dave", 45, 2019-01-01T08:00:00Z),
//   Employee("John", 20, 2019-01-03T08:00:00Z),
//   Employee("John", 30, 2019-01-02T08:00:00Z),
//   Employee("Sue",  20, 2019-01-02T08:00:00Z)
// )
```

As a side note, in case a different ordering, say `joinedDate, name, age`, is wanted:

```
implicit val employeeOrdering: Ordering[Employee] = Ordering.by(
  e => (e.joinedDate, e.name, e.age)
)
```